# Read the GET request headers for a resource on an external site

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, security, xss

Is it possible to read the GET REQUEST headers for a given EXTERNAL resource in a page?

Similar to this:

```
<script>
  var headers = <?php echo json_encode(getallheaders()); ?>; 
</script>
```

This will only return the request headers for the current page. I am looking to get the request headers for a specific external element.

```
<html>
<img src="externaldomain.com/image.png" />
<script>

var = document.img.getAllRequestHeaders(); // How to do this??
</script>
</html>
```

I DO NOT want to read the response headers. (Which is blocked by CORS anyway)

When loading the example html, imagine that you can see the various request headers in the Network panel.

I want to access a specific header, set by the browser, for this resource.

Edit: Also, any relevant cookies that might already be active in the browser. Are they accessible?

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't read the http headers for an object like that - you'd need to make a new request. And as you said, you'd run into CORS.  What header did you want to read, this may be an XY problem, and there is a better way of getting the information you need. What kind of cookies are you trying to read. You are kinda vague in this question which makes it hard to answer.